# Fastest Algorithm for Inverse of Positive-Definite Hermitian Toeplitz Matrix?

Tags: algebra

The Trench algorithm (1996) has complexity N*N to invert an N by N positive-definite Hermitian Toeplitz matrix. More recently (2005), Martinsson et al "A Fast Algorithm for the Inversion of General Toeplitz Matrices" describe an algorithm with complexity NlogN for general Toeplitz matrices but the intrinsic complexity is such that the breakeven point with respect to the Trench algorithm occurs near N=1000. My interest is N approximately equal to 512.
Can anyone advise of any more recent research and the fastest algorithm for the specific case of inverting positive-definite Hermitian Toeplitz matrices of size ballpark 512?
As an aside, I specifically need the inverse matrix (rather than solving linear equations Levinson-Durbin style) since the next step requires summing diagonal terms of the inverse matrix.

Comment: Don't you mean that you don't need the inverse but the trace of the inverse ?

Comment: The standard way to find out whether there is more recent research is to go to [Google Scholar](https://scholar.google.com/) (or one of its competitors), search for that paper, click to view the papers that cite it, and review them to see if they have made any relevant progress.  Since this is a problem you care about, I think it would be best if you did that, and then [edit]ed the paper to report what you've found.  If you don't find anything, odds are that there is no relevant progress, as any follow-on research is likely to cite one of those two papers.